# DocumentDb stored procedures and optimistic concurrency

Tags: stored-procedures, azure-cosmosdb

My goal is to write a stored procedure or a trigger that allows me to read-replace a document and then update a metadata document in one transaction.

Now I know this will work as intended if I write to the collection sequentially but what if I am executing multiple stored procedures in parallel, do I have to manually configure the script to compare the etags or is that the default behavior for server side scripts?

After reading some examples in [this article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/documentdb-programming/) I got the impression that the transaction would automatically fail if the etag had changed in the middle of the read-replace operation.
In [this example](https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-js-server/blob/master/samples/stored-procedures/update.js) however the author includes the etag in a requestOptions object and passes that into the replaceDocument method, similarly how I have been doing it with the .NET SDK on the client side.

These inconsistencies got me confused. So my question is: For server side scripts, is it necessary to include the etag in a requestOptions object to enforce optimistic concurrency or is that the default behavior?

Comment: This is a good question. I've always used etags in my [sprocs](https://github.com/lmaccherone/documentdb-utils/blob/master/sprocs/updateSomeDocuments.coffee) (maybe defensively) which is in conflict with my understanding that each sproc runs in isolation and there is no chance for reads and writes to see an inconsistent view, which makes me think that it's not necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each script runs as one transaction. Due to snapshot isolation, when two scripts update same document, if one succeeds to update, and they both started at snapshot when the doc was not updated, the other would fail, and after that there is no way for the other to update the doc, as it can't read version of the doc which if later than its snapshot, the script would have to exit/return to client, and the client would have to execute the script again. Because of that using etags for concurrently protection is not helpful.